# How to pass SSL keystore password?

Tags: java, security, ssl, web, keystore

I am writing a little web framework and I want to enable SSL encryption with a SSL key which will be supplied by the user.

This might seem overly cautious, but is it common to pass the password for the keystore file as a `String` passed in the parameters of a method?

This is what I had in mind:

```
public void enableSSL(String keystorePath, String keystorePassword) {
    // ... do things
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**It is always safer to store the password into character array than a string.**

Please refer below query:
[Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords-in-java)

Also refer the below coding guide lines from oracle site:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#2

Comment: Please mark this question as duplicate rather than trying to feed off someone elses's answer.